# Flex VideoDisplay text quality

Tags: apache-flex, flash, video

I am trying to display arbitrary mp4 videos in a flex application. Often videos have text on them.

Sometimes when I have to scale the video down (on the client size height or width less then videoHeight or videoWidth) keeping the aspect ratio Flash Player makes text look blurry.

Is there way to tell Flash to handle scaling more accurate?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea if this will work but: you can maybe try to [Enable Smoothing on VideoDisplay](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=3561)

Comment: This setting actually improves the text quality. Not that text becomes a lot easier to read it just doesn't look as distorted as it looked before. Shapes look more like text.